# Java - Use specific element of a list

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

My function return a List of string array. how i access/print only the first string array from the list in main().

```
public class URLReader{
public  List<String[]> functie(String x) throws Exception{
...
List<String[]> substrList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
substrList.add(tds2);
substrList.add(tds3);
return substrList;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
URLReader s = new URLReader();
for (??????????)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers have stated already, to use the first element in a list, you would call the List.get(int) method.

```
someList.get(0);
```

In your code, in order to iterate over the String array in the first list index, you would want something that looks like:

```
for( String str : s.functie(arg).get(0) ) {
    //Do something with the string such as...
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over all arrays (what you started writing in your question:

```
for (String[] array : s.functie("...")) {
     ...
}
```

If you only want the first one:

```
String[] array = array.get(0);
```

Comment: "functie" use a string argument. i call the function s.functie(x); where x is an URL

Comment: @Bogdan S: Ok, use it with a url then! :)

Comment: My function gets a url as parameter and return a list of two String Array (first contain a String array of links, and second a string array of description). In main() i need to access only the first element of the list and print it. Can you please be more specific. Thank you

Comment: I think you mean `s.functie("...").get(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first element from a list like so:

```
final List<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
arrayList.get(0); // get first element
```

Or you can use a queue, which has built in methods for such tasks.

```
final Queue<String[]> linkedList = new LinkedList<String[]>();
linkedList.poll(); // get (and remove) first element
linkedList.peek(); // get (but do not remove) first element
```